# Apache xmlrpc - Client notification

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I just started using apache xmlrpc library.
I was wondering how it is possible to create two way communication, so that
server can notify client about some events. When I was using RMI it was
possible to send Server RemoteObject, that caused connection from server
to client. 
Is it possible to do this with xmlrpc? Actually I want to send some 'remote' listener
to server so client will be notified without the need to ask server if there
has been some changes.

Thanks.
Jure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is able to run a lightweight server, like [Apache's xmlrpc WebServer class](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/apidocs/org/apache/xmlrpc/webserver/WebServer.html), then the Server could call the client for notifications.

1. Server starts up
2. Client starts up and makes requests to the server
3. Client calls a "register" method on the server, passing in it's hostname and port as params
4. Client starts up the lightweight server to listen for notifications
5. When notification event occurs, Server looks through it's list of registered clients, and calls them